# What are the browser versions displayed selenium grid console?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

What are the browser versions displayed in grid console?

[image: Selenium Grid Console]

while creating node I haven't specified browser version then what is browser version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Selenium Grid Hub Console](http://localhost:4444/grid/console) shows the pictorial representation of WebDriver support to different variants of WebBrowsers within *Selenium Grid* irrespective of any *Browser Version*.

Snapshot:

[image: GridConsole]

The above picture represents:

- `maxInstances` of **Firefox** supported: 5
- `maxInstances` of **Chrome** supported: 5
- `maxInstances` of **Internet Explorer** supported: 1

---

If you take a step further and click on the **`Configuration`** tab you will get the induvidual detailed configuration for each type of browser as:

- *Firefox*:

  ```
  capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: firefox, marionette: true, maxInstances: 5, platform: WIN8, platformName: WIN8, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: 69d77ffb-d8e0-4b50-b48d-8bd...}
  ```
- *Chrome*:

  ```
  capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, maxInstances: 5, platform: WIN8, platformName: WIN8, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: 8285b9c4-971e-4cff-bbe7-5fe...}
  ```
- *Internet Explorer*:

  ```
  capabilities: Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, maxInstances: 1, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: 49978d76-fae9-49e8-99ef-1ec...}
  ```
- Snapshot:

[image: capabilities]

Comment: but is there any way to know what browser version grid will invoke?

Comment: @GoodVibes When you register the node you have to mention the capabilities i.e. the browser version which the node will support.

Comment: should node contain driver files(chromedriver.exe) ??to run test cases on chrome browser on node